# Multithreading socket in Python. I'm missing something

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, global-variables

I'm learning the use of multithreading and sockets in python so I'm sorry if I lack knowledge...

I'm stuck with this problem:
I took this code from this forum and I tried to do some modify.

I would like to have the main thread which start a thread which listen for connection and for each connection start a new thread.

In the meanwhile the main thread has to do something (in this case print the globalVar). The globalVar is inscreased by 1 every message received.

The result with this code is:

```
Hi!
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
('192.168.2.226', 5601)
```

The "hello!" string never shows up! and the globalVar isn't printed at all.
What am I gettin wrong?

This is the code:

```
import socket
import threading

globalVar = 0
class ThreadedServer(object):
    global globalVar
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        global globalVar
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    # Set the response to echo back the recieved data
                    #response = data
                    print(address)
                    globalVar += 1
                    #client.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False
print("Hi!")
threading.Thread(target=ThreadedServer('',5050).listen()).start()
print("Hello!")
while True:
    print(globalVar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target=ThreadedServer('',5050).listen())`

should be

`target=ThreadedServer('',5050).listen)`

It's freezing because you're *calling* the `listen` function, rather than passing it as an argument. Because `listen` has an endless loop in it, the thread is never even started, because it's waiting for the function to return a value.

Comment: @G.Threepwood No problem. And don't forget to accept my answer.